# Душить духами и душить удавкой

Tags: омонимы

Как мы знаем, духами можно душиться самому, а можно душить кого-то. А еще ими можно надушить или надушиться.
При этом душить еще можно удавкой. Сразу вспоминается Шариковское "Душили, душили!"
Тут всегда просят предлагать свою версию. Моя такая: и там, и там - дух. Только в первом случае "дух" в значении "запах", а в другом - "дыхание, жизнь".
Но все-таки, можно ли считать слова "душить (духами)" и "душить (удавкой)" омонимами?

Answer (score 3):

ДУШИТЬ (1) - убивать, с силой сжимая горло.   ДУШИТЬ (2) - опрыскивать, смачивать духами, одеколоном.

В языкознании  различают омонимию и полисемию. Омонимия — это случайное совпадение слов, в то время как полисемия  (многозначность)— наличие у слова разных, но  исторически связанных значений.

При этом существуют следующие варианты для определения ПОЛИСЕМИИ (разные точки зрения в лингвистике):

1)  слова исторически связаны, но только лингвисты видят эту связь;

2) слова исторически связаны, и это видят большинство носителей языка;

3)  историческая связь не учитывается, полисемия в любом случае  – это частный случай омонимии.

Таким образом, слово «душить» в двух его значениях при разных подходах можно считать: а) разными значениями одного слова; б) омонимами.